# Pattern for Express/Node dependencies: Can I use a separate services file for "app" instance?

Tags: node.js, express, require, dependency-management, circular-dependency

I have an express/node app and I want to make the app instance available in multiple files without running into circular references (e.g. before the routes object was included with express, you would have needed to export the app object into a routes.js file but then that routes.js file is then exported back into the main app.js file).

While I know the routes object solves this usecase, I'm trying to figure out if a different pattern would work / is best practice.

SO...could I have a separate services file where I require express then in that services file create the app? And have my main root folder as well as n other folders (that could each have their own circularities) safely require the app from this service.

```
Example Folder structure
├── app.js   // main file; ordinarily would have required routes.js
├── routes
    ├── routes.js // ordinarily would have required top app.js for app object
├── services
    ├── firebase.js
    ├── amplitude.js
    └── app.js // instead, create app here and export it to both above
```

So for example, the three files could look like this:

**app.js (main)**

```
const app = require('./services/app');
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on port 3000));
```

**routes/routes.js**

```
const app = require('../services/app');
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('hello world'));
```

**services/app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
module.exports.app = app;
```

**Is this safe / best practice?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's `module.exports.app = app`, it should be not

```
const app = require('./services/app');
```

but

```
const { app } = require('./services/app');
```

It doesn't look very elegant but it will work.

Since `routes.js`, etc should be loaded in strict order in order for middlewares and routes to work properly, this approach doesn't make them loosely coupled and doesn't provide obvious benefits.

A common practice is to do the opposite and load middlewares in `app.js`. Routes don't need `app` instance, as described in [this guide](http://express-router) they can use router instance and then be mounted to `/` in entry point:

*routes.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('hello world'));

module.exports = router;
```

*app.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const router = require('./routes');

app.use('/', router);
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on port 3000'));
```

Comment: thanks, estus! Will keep this in mind.  My question was poorly worded, as I meant to talk about services in general (e.g. the "pool" instance when working with SQL databases, the "amplitude" instance when working with logging, etc.).  When the instance of some service is required in multiple files, I was trying to figure out a pattern that will allow the same instance to be used across multiple files.  Per your answer, it seems like express has given an elegant solution (i.e. routes) but for other libraries without such an option, the services file approach will work.  Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: JS modules (CJS, ES, whatever) naturally provide singleton instances because they are evaluated only on first import. So yes, it makes sense to export db instance from 'service' module and import it everywhere, that's how it's usually done. As for Express, it provides [settings table](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.settings.table) to manage app things, including db instances. So you could do `app.set('db', instance)` in main file and use `app.get('db')` anywhere else (that's where your original  services/app.js approach could be helpful). It isn't mandatory, just one of possible ways.